# Ruby: merge results of two methods from a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a class called `TemplateResources` that has two methods like this:

```
def components
  @template.components
end

def custom_articles
  components += @user.custom_articles if @user.custom_articles.present?
end
```

The results are called in a view like so:

```
<% @template_resources.components.each do |article| %>
```

I want the *combined* results displayed in the view. I thought the `+=` would do that, but it doesn't seem to. Anyone know how to join the results of those two methods?

Comment: Can you please describe model relationships between template, user, custom_articles and components. That we help to understand and answer the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
def components
  @template.components
end

def custom_articles
  @user.custom_articles || []
end

def all_articles
  components + custom_articles
end
```

And than in the view:

```
<% @template_resources.all_articles.each do |article| %>
```

Comment: Far out that's simple. Thanks!